# Unexpected query layer results: Why does unioning with DUAL fix it?

Tags: arcgis-10.3, enterprise-geodatabase, sql, query-layer, unique-id

**Simple Query:**

I have a query that connects to a table in a work order management database (Oracle 12c; non-GDB).

```
select 
    wo.wonum
from 
    maximo.workorder wo
```

The query returns 428 records in [Toad](https://www.quest.com/products/toad-for-oracle/) and 428 records in a [query layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/what-is-a-query-layer-.htm) (in ArcMap).

This result is expected.

---

**Complex Query:**

If I change the query so that it joins to a related table:

```
select 
    cast(rownum as number(38,0)) as rownum_,
    wo.wonum
from 
    maximo.workorder wo
left join 
    maximo.wfassignment a 
    on wo.workorderid = a.ownerid
```

the query returns 1048 records in Toad and **428** records in the query layer.

This result is **unexpected**. The query layer ought to have returned 1048 records, just like Toad.

---

**Analysis:**

I understand that query layers often have a hard time with queries that are not 1 to 1 with an underlying table.

- I don't know for sure, but I think query layers like to have a unique ID that comes from a column in a real table.
- Sure, with simple 1 to 1 queries, rownum can often do the trick as a unique ID. But for complex queries (with joins that propagate-out additional records), rownum seems to be problematic.

---

**A Solution:**

Through trial an error, I came up with a solution that **works with the joined table** in the query layer:

```
select
    cast(null as number(38,0)) as rownum_,
    null as wonum
from 
    dual
where
    1<>1

union all

select 
    cast(rownum as number(38,0)) as rownum_,
    wo.wonum
from 
    maximo.workorder wo
left join 
    maximo.wfassignment a 
    on wo.workorderid = a.ownerid
```

The query returns 1048 records in Toad and 1048 records in the query layer.

This result is expected.

---

**Question:**

Why does unioning to the **dual table** make the complex query **work properly** in the query layer?